# "Ao que" ou à "o que"?

Tags: diferenças, acentuação

Qual das duas é a correta: "Ao que" ou "à o que"?

Por exemplo:

> Isto está relacionado ao que ela não podia me contar antes?

ou

> Isto está relacionado à o que ela não podia me contar antes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O correto é:

> Isto está relacionado ao que ela não podia me contar antes?

Se *algo* está relacionado, está relacionado **a *algo***, portanto pede preposição 'a'. O ***algo*** de sua frase é o 'o que ela não podia me contar antes' — por começar com '*o*', o '*a*' se funde a ele, formando '*ao*'; da mesma forma que '*de*' + '*ele*' = '*dele*'.

A formulação "... à o que ela" seria o mesmo que "a a o que ela" — sendo que o primeiro '*a*' é preposição e o segundo é artigo —, o que não faz sentido.

---

Uma análise sintática mais completa da estrutura correta seria:

```
[Isto]¹ [está relacionado ao que ela não podia me contar antes]?²
```

¹ - sujeito

² - predicado

```
[Isto]¹ [está]² [relacionado]³ [ao que ela não podia me contar antes]⁴?
```

¹ - sujeito

² - verbo

³ - predicativo do sujeito

⁴ - oração subordinada substantiva completiva nominal (complemento nominal de "*relacionado*")

```
[Isto]¹ [está]² [relacionado]³ a[o que]⁴ [ela]⁵ [não]⁶ [podia]⁷ [me]⁸ [contar]⁹ [antes]¹⁰?
```

¹ - sujeito

² - verbo

³ - predicativo do sujeito

⁴ - objeto direto

⁵ - sujeito

⁶ - adjunto adverbial de negação

⁷ - verbo

⁸ - objeto indireto

⁹ - verbo

¹⁰ - adjunto adverbial de tempo